# How do I clear the animation frame on new information input?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an animation of a figure 8 moving across the screen and I cant seem to figure out how to clear the animation when new information is input into the text boxes.

When user input into the text boxes, the animation starts, but i'd like any new input to reset the animation from the beginning.

I think it has to do with the loop set to only 20.

How do I reset the loop and restart the animation on new user input?

```
function redraw() {
polyline.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

This does not seem to do anything.

```
A= <input type="text" id="amp" onkeyup="tick(), redraw()" size="4"></input>
```

i'm also calling two functions withing the onkeyup in the box.

https://codepen.io/braydendevito/pen/EzJjgP

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is as soon as a key is pressed you're calling **tick()** and **redraw()** - that means any global variable that are used inside those functions will keep the last value.
The two variables causing this behaviour are **frame** - which should be reset to 0 and the **points** array reset to an empty array.

```
<div align="center">
  A= <input type="text" id="amp" onkeyup="reset();" size="4"></input>
  A= <input type="text" id="freq" onkeyup="reset();" size="4"></input>
  A= <input type="text" id="speed" onkeyup="reset();" size="4"></input>
</div>


function reset()
{
  frame=0;
  points=[];
  tick();
  redraw();
}
```